# Ruby on Rails: rails3_fullcalendar updating event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

I'm trying to start an app based on this application
 https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar

I run `rake db:migrate` from the root of the folder I extracted from the downloaded zip, then I start the server.

When I navigate to `localhost:3000` I see the calendar, and everything works fine. 
I can enter an event which then appears in the database, and appears correctly on the calendar.

The problems start when I try to move an event, The event moves, and the date is changed, but as soon as I leave the page, the event disappears from the calendar even though it is still in the database.

Has anyone had this trouble using this example application? The example is over 2 years old so could it be to do with the version of rails or ruby I am using, (Rails 3.0.7, ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [i686-linux])

Might be best just to download and run yourself to see what I mean. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should open an issue on github project's page.